# Issue scraping ul section of page

Tags: python, scrapy, html-lists, screen-scraping

**Set-up**

I'm scraping housing ads with scrapy.

I successfully collect most of the housing characteristics per ad, to subsequently analyse them with pandas.

---

**Problem**

I cannot seem to scrape a certain `ul` on an ad page. The issue concerns the sections 'Main features' and 'Extras' on any housing ad page: e.g. [this one](http://www.fotocasa.es/en/home/barcelona-capital/heating-lift-furnished-regente-mendieta-11-13-142804619).

When I try to scrape the elements, I receive a blank return.

---

**Tries**

I've tried the following to obtain the 'Extras'

```
response.css("section.divFeatures") # empty 

response.css("div.detail-section-content::text", # gives me the property location (strange)
          ).extract() 

response.css("#divFeatures").extract() # empty
```

And the list go's on.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I successfully obtain the elements?

Comment: That's because this data is loaded through javascript with [this](http://www.fotocasa.es/ws/DetailModular.asmx/GetPrincipalFeatures?adId=142804619&promotionId=0&tti=3&periodicityId=3&culture=en-US) url

Comment: Thanks Casper! Just for my understanding, the url in your comment, would that be scrapable? And if so, did you fetch it from the page's code somewhere?

Comment: Yes that url would be scrapable. I'm not sure whether there are better ways to see where the data is coming from but I'm just opening the inspect window in Chrome and then use the Network tab to see what data is loaded. Eventually you'll find a page like this one containing the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can query that page mentioned by @Casper directly...or you can use an engine that runs the javascript and edits the DOM for you like a regular webbrowser and get the html after it's been edited.

Selenium+ChromeDriver(+XVFB if you want to run headless) or phantomjs etc.  Those will run all the javascript on a webpage and have the exact same structure as what you see when you open the inspect panel in chrome.